# Difference between ERB#result and ERB#run

Tags: ruby, erb

This is erb3.rb

```
require 'erb'

weekday = Time.now.strftime('%A')
simple_template = "Today is <%= weekday %>."

renderer = ERB.new(simple_template)
puts renderer.result
renderer.run
```

When I run this I get the followings.

```
➜ ruby erb3.rb
Today is Friday.
Today is Friday.%
```

Q1. I understand that I don't need to write `puts renderer.run`. But are there any more differences?

Q2. The output of `put renderer.run` is `Today is Friday.%`. What is % at the end. When I use `puts renderer.run` then it doesn't output %.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding Q1, there is no difference between writing `puts renderer.result` or `renderer.run`. 
UPDATE: Thank you @muistooshort for pointing out the source for `run`:

```
def run(b=new_toplevel)
  print self.result(b)
end
```

As you can see, it is simply printing the output of `result`.

---

Regarding Q2, I believe the % just indicates a new line. If you change your script to the following it goes away.

```
renderer = ERB.new(simple_template)
puts renderer.result
renderer.run
puts ""
#>Today is Thursday.
#>Today is Thursday.
```

Comment: `run` is, in fact, simply `print self.result(b)`: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-i-run

Comment: Since no one's said it explicitly yet, it bears mentioning: `puts` adds a newline at the end of its output, while `print` does not.

Answer (score 0):

`renderer.run` prints the result meaning that there is no new newline after the output which is  indicated by the `%` (I guess because you are using zsh). You can get the same result like this:

```
➜ puts 'a'; print 'a'
a
a%
```